# Most efficient way to turn (x=y) into true?

Tags: c#

As an exercise in learning the C# language, I would like to do an integer assignment x=y but then return the boolean true.

```
bool b=(x=y)==y;
```

This works but its a bit smelly. 
Is there a C# operator or casting method that turns an integer into a bool?

This is a predicate to the next exercise which involves yet another horrible hack.

Comment: whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat !!!

Comment: The whole *aim* is smelly. What's wrong with `x = y; return true;` ? If your aim is to learn C#, why not restrict yourself to reasonable code?

Comment: `"(...)the next exercise which involves yet another horrible hack."` If you yourself admit that your learning source is no good, then you should look for other learning sources.

Comment: It looks like he's trying to do the whole "C/C++" thing... if (x=y) {}

Comment: Don't do it this way! This made my day, though.

Comment: Goal is unclear, so voting to close. If you want some painful but much more C#-friendly exercise read and understand something like [Recursive lambda expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx)... much more useful/readable that obscure syntax hacks. Note that this may be ok question for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com, but not good for SO due to attempt to write unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool b = (y = x) is int;
```

Enjoy your compiler warnings.

Comment: Note that unlike original code it no longer guaranteed to return `true` all the time for all types of `x`/`y`... so different from original code... Can't really upvote even if it answers the question because sample is so strange and guaranteed to confuse me if I ever see such code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Interesting, I was not aware of this. In what circumstances (assuming y and x are always int as the question states) would this return false? I though that integer assignment would always return an integer, which in turn would always be evaluated by 'is int' as true?

Comment: I meant type of `x` and `y` different from `int` (like `string x,y`), indeed if it is guaranteed to be int it is `true` (and answers OP's question).